# How do you access a models related properties using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm developing a simple application that will allow users to create a profile and upload multiple images. I'm using ASP.NET Identity and will therefore refer to "user" as `ApplicationUser`. I have an `Image` and an `ApplicationUser` domain model shown below:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
        public string UserSurname { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Image> Image { get; set; }
    }
```

And

```
    public class Image
    {
        public int ImageID { get; set; }
        public string ImageCaption { get; set; }
        public int NumOfLikes { get; set; }
        public string ImageFilePath { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        //public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

I added `public virtual ICollection<Image> Image { get; set; }` and `public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }` to define a one-to-many relationship between `ApplicationUser` and `Image`. After running the application I noticed that Entity Framework had created `ApplicationUser_id` in the Images table (Which I assume I can use as a foreign key without having to uncomment the code in the `Image` domain model).
I also have `ViewImagesViewModel` which will return to a view, a collection of images which I would like to be able to filter and sort by `ApplicationUser`'s name,surname and city. My problem is that I don't know how to combine the properties from both domain models into a single view model.

---

### Questions

1. How do I access or return `ApplicationUser`'s properties when returning `Image`?
2. How do I bind `Image`'s related attributes such as `ApplicationUser`'s `UserFirstName` to `ViewImagesViewModel`?

Comment: can you show the `ViewImagesViewModel` code?

Comment: also show us the code in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the required data 'eagerly loaded' into one model, you can use `Include`

When fetching an image, you can also fetch the user:

```
var image = context.Images.Include(i => i.ApplicationUser).FirstOrDefault(i => i.ImageId == imageId);
```

or the reverse, when fetching a user you can fetch all images for that user:

```
var user = context.ApplicationUser.Include(u => u.Image).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
```

After that, you can access `image.ApplicationUser.UserSurname`. See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: How do you access the images in the example you've provided? `user.Image[0].ImageId`?

Comment: You can use `foreach (var image in user.Image) {}` to list all images or `user.Image.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first image for that user or `null` if that user has no images. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

as you said you have a `ViewImagesViewModel`, 
so I thought that this viewmodel should be something like that

```
public class ViewImagesViewModel 
{
    public void ViewImagesViewModel() 
    {
        this.Images = new List<ViewImageViewModel>();
    }

    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserSurname { get; set; } 
    public string City { get; set; }

    public List<ViewImageViewModel> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ViewImageViewModel
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int Likes { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

and below is how you could map the domain entities to your viewmodel, in the controller action do it like that

```
...
var entity = db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);

if (entity != null) 
{
    var model = new ViewImagesViewModel();
    model.UserFirstName = entity.UserFirstName;
    model.UserSurname = entity.UserSurname;
    model.City = entity.City;

    // fix the Image property in the ApplicationUser entity to be Images instead of Image as it represent a collection
    foreach (var img in entity.Images)
    {
        var imgModel = new ViewImageViewModel()
        {
            // you may change this to get the correct Url
            ImageUrl = string.Concat(HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, 
                  "://", HttpContext.Request.Url.Host, 
                  HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath,
                  img.ImageFilePath),
            Likes = img.NumOfLikes,
            Caption = img.Caption
        };

        model.Images.Add(imgModel);
    }

    return View(model);
}
...
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, I'm fairly new to asp.net and am still grasping the basics. Your controller appears to be one that I would use to fetch all images of a single user. My issue is that I don't/didn't know how to return all images with their related user's name, surname and city. I thought I had to include these properties in my `Image` domain model to map the relationship between each image and the details of its owner.